# Custom hook not running after changing router Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook to load external script. Here is my hook:

```
    export default function useScript(scripts: string[]) {
        const [state, setState] = useState({
            loaded: false,
            error: false
        });

        useEffect(
            () => {
                scripts.forEach(src => {
                    if (cachedScripts.includes(src)) {
                        setState({
                            loaded: true,
                            error: false
                        });
                    } else {
                        cachedScripts.push(src);
                        // Create script
                        let script = document.createElement('script');
                        script.src = src;
                        script.async = true;
                        // Add script to document body
                        document.body.appendChild(script);
                    }
                })
            setState({
                loaded: true,
                error: false
            });
            },
            [] // Only re-run effect if script src changes
        );

        return [state.loaded, state.error];
    }


    const Scripts: React.FC = () => {
        const publicURL = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;
        useScripts(scripts);
        return (
            <>
            </>
        )
    };

    export default Scripts;
```

It work once in first time but when redirect router it not work anymore. I change my code a litte bit to -

```
    const Scripts: React.FC = () => {
        const publicURL = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;
         useEffect(() => {
             scripts.forEach(src => {
                 let script = document.createElement('script');
                 script.src = src;
                 script.async = true;
                 document.body.appendChild(script);
             })
         }, []);
        return (
            <>
            </>
        )
    };

export default Scripts;
```

And it worked but I don't know why. Can anyone explain that for me? Thank in advance

Comment: that does not look like a little change.. no idea what you mean by `it worked` since the 2nd version should run only once, when `<Scripts />` is mounted, same as the 1st version.. the only difference seems to be about `cachedScripts`

Comment: @Aprillion I buy a template html so it have a ton of external script. When I change to 2nd version, it script can run after I routing between screen, but in 1st version it only run once time